# "How to de-unzip" vs "How to cleanup root"

Tags: discussion, status-completed

For quite some time we have this question: [How to de-unzip, de-tar -xvf — de-unarchive in a messy folder?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5123/250)

Yesterday in quite a panic I asked this question: [Clean up / after accidentally extracting archive into it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6686/250)

The main difference is, I run the "de-unzip" as root, which is more stupid and need some special considerations. Apart from that the two questions are the same.

Now is that enough to keep them as two questions? Or should I delete mine? Or should we merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we delete my answer and edit yours a bit to avoid specifically using `cpio` (since the other question is more generic) we can probably merge them. Merging is pretty difficult since there's usually minor differences that make answers from one question confusing when attached to another, but yours has so few answers that it's not a problem. I'll merge it a little later unless somebody raises a strong objection (seems unlikely)